# PHP - How to Sort in a foreach loop alphabetically for the name not the ID?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting, multidimensional-array

How can I sort by $event->post_title when it's already inside the foreach statement?

This is code from a WordPress plugin if that helps.

I believe the following will sort it by the ID, not the "post_title":
sort(events);

```
    $events = get_posts(array('post_type'=>$this->main->get_main_post_type(), 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1));

    echo '<select>';
    foreach($events as $event) {
        echo '<option class="'.$event->post_title.'" value="'.$event->ID.'" '.($mec_event_id == $event->ID ? 'selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$event->post_title.' -test3</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
```

Comment: You might want to check out the code in $this->main->get_main_post_type() and see if you can sort it there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function **uasort** and pass a comparison function defined by you.

See the example below.

```php
<?php
//creating sample data
$events[0] = new stdClass();
$events[0]->name = 'Class';
$events[0]->date = '2020-09-01';
$events[0]->place = 'Home';
$events[0]->user = 'Jhon';

$events[1] = new stdClass();
$events[1]->name = 'Meeting';
$events[1]->date = '2020-09-21';
$events[1]->place = 'Office';
$events[1]->user = 'Will';

$events[2] = new stdClass();
$events[2]->name = 'Lecture';
$events[2]->date = '2020-09-1';
$events[2]->place = 'Schoool';
$events[2]->user = 'Anna';

uasort($events, function($a, $b){
    //sorting by the field 'user'
    return strcmp($a->user, $b->user);
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r($events);

//OUTPUT
Array
(
    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Lecture
            [date] => 2020-09-1
            [place] => Schoool
            [user] => Anna
        )

    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Class
            [date] => 2020-09-01
            [place] => Home
            [user] => Jhon
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [name] => Meeting
            [date] => 2020-09-21
            [place] => Office
            [user] => Will
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to order before you get to the loop... you can look for a filter to sort it like `pre_get_posts` or you can just add some params to the call like below...

add `'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'` to you `get_posts` call like:

```
$events = get_posts(array('post_type'=>$this->main->get_main_post_type(), 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page'=>-1, 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC'));

echo '<select>';
foreach($events as $event) {
    echo '<option class="'.$event->post_title.'" value="'.$event->ID.'" '.($mec_event_id == $event->ID ? 'selected="selected"' : '').'>'.$event->post_title.' -test3</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Example from the `get_posts` docs page: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/#comment-1190